# How to fix a CSS file blanked out like this?

Tags: css, atom-editor

I was writing code and suddenly power was gone and the PC turned off (I don't have UPS for now). When I turned it on and opened the editor I saw this -

[--code blanked out--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHeub.png)

This only happened with the CSS file. I did save what I wrote before the power cut. I was only reviewing the code...

Is there a way to retrieve the code?

Comment: that's a good reason to use a version control system like Git. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

Comment: Your file has probably been corrupted. Another issue, I wouldn't suggest using Atom since it's not going be maintained anymore and will be closed down soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved the code, then you may check closing and reopening file. This may be application generated message there.